# Measure zero set in $\mathbb{R}$ and related questions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $Z\subset\mathbb{R}$ have measure zero.

Then, is it true that $Z$ is either an empty set or a set of countable points?

And, can the set of all irrationals in $[0,1]$ contain an interval? If not, how can we say that it has measure $1$ except the argument using the fact that the set of all rationals in $[0,1]$ has measure zero?

So, can a set with positive measure not contain any interval? If not, how do we measure it?

Comment: I believe the Cantor set has measure zero, but is uncountable. No set of irrationals will ever contain an open set, as then it would contain a rational number, by density

Comment: Look at Sard's Theorem for examples of a certain type.

Comment: It's even possible to have a set $Z$ of measure zero that's so dense that $Z \cap I$ is uncountable for every interval $I \subseteq \mathbb R$. Just take $Z = \{ c+q \, | \, c \in \mathcal C, q \in \mathbb Q \}$, where $\mathcal C$ is the ordinary Cantor set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not true.

Take $C$ the Cantor set, defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).

- It has measure zero, since for all epsilon you can construct balls getting smaller and smaller containing all points of $C$, and such that the sum of the measure of all these balls will be $<\epsilon$.
- It is uncountable because it is equipotent to $\{0,1,2\}^{\mathbb N}$ which is not countable.

---

For your second question, yes it is possible to find a set with positive measure not containing any interval.

It can be done by modifying slightly the construction of the Cantor set.

Comment: But if we follow the construction of Cantor, don't we get measure zero like the Cantor set? I can't imagine certain situation that a set with positive measure does not contain any interval. The set of all irrationals, however, looks like having positive measure without containing any inteval, and that's why I am confused. I can't accept, or feel that it has positive measure while I can understand the proof and follow the logic.

Comment: I guess it's because the irrationals look descrete, or the rationals are so dense

Comment: Yes, the ordinary Cantor set has measure zero. But it is not countable, so it proves that the answer to your question "Then, is it true that $Z$ is either an empty set or a set of countable points?" is *no*.

Comment: There are modifications of the construction of the Cantor set where instead of always removing $1/3$ of what's left, you remove smaller fractions in such a way that what's left has not measure zero, but will still be nondense and not contain any interval.